# How should I find a telescope for research time?

Tags: telescope, astrophysics, space-telescope, protostar, astrochemistry

I'm an undergrad in physics and astronomy deciding to look into applying for time on a research telescope, and I'm not sure how to proceed with locating/finding telescopes that I can apply for time on. Specifically, I'm interested in looking at the chemical composition of protostellar disk(s). Any applicable information would be nice.

Comment: How are you intending to find the chemical composition of protostellar disks? You probably need mid- to far-infrared spectroscopy of mm-wave observations or possibly radio observations? Your question is too vague to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As an undergraduate, you are a member of a university. Your first step then should be to talk to your Professors.

As a guide to what might be expected, look at the [University of Arizona telescope proposal page](https://www.as.arizona.edu/telescope-proposals) They accept proposals from members of Arizona University. You have to have a clear aim and plan. This is why you need to talk to your professors first.